# com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: Occupants with these IDs do not exist

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

QuickBlox Chat was working fine from last 6 months but now from last 4 to 5 days I am getting this error **com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: Occupants with these IDs do not exist.** while creating a private chat dialog. Occupant id is the id of owner of chat portal from which i am trying to create a Private chat. I don't know why it is happening now the same code which was working now stops working. Anyone can tell me why this issue starts coming now.

Code to Create a private chat dialog :

```
privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
privateChatManager.createDialog(7094465, new QBEntityCallback<QBDialog>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
         Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onError: ");
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Occupant id is the id of owner of chat portal from which i am trying to create a Private chat" - you should not do this anymore.
You have to use regular API users to chat with, not Dashboard admin.

The feature with access to API from Dashboard admin is deprecated and will be completely reviewed (new better solution will be proposed).